# Rails: strong_params and getter/setter methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getter-setter, strong-parameters

I'm using strong_params in Rails 4. When I try using a custom setter method like this:

```
def foo=(foo)
  @foo = foo
end
```

Then Rails records the attribute as null within the database. If I remove the custom setter, then everything works fine. In Rails 3, custom setters were written like this, but perhaps things have changed? If so, how do custom setters now work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this code worked on Rails 3. Are you certain about this? Because if you do this, you override the setter method created by ActiveRecord (which is responsible for storing data to DB). Does your custom version of method look exactly like shown? What's the point of it?

Try calling `super`.

```
def foo=(foo)
  @foo = foo
  super
end
```

P.S.: I checked and it does **not** work in Rails 3 (works with `super`).

Comment: Calling super does the trick. I remember getting similar methods to work in Rails 3, but they must have been just virtual attributes. Either way, thanks for the clarification. This helps alot.